# How can I progammmatically determine which processes are actively using my webcam on OSX?

Tags: macos, webcam

I'm writing a utility that addresses a Bluetooth status indicator light when my webcam is in use so that I'm not disturbed during meetings while working from home. Presently, I'm parsing the output of `lsof` to see which processes have a file descriptor open to `VDC`, but this approach is fraught for a number of reasons:

- Not all processes with a FD to `VDC` are actually using the webcam (ex: `avconfere`, the Facetime daemon, and Chrome, which always holds a FD if it is open).
- Most processes spin up a second process when the webcam is actually in use, and that child process doesn't always share a name in common with its parent, meaning I have to maintain a mapping to know which program is using the webcam.
- Some applications (like Zoom) don't release the webcam FD when the webcam stops being used (only when Zoom is killed completely).

Is there any other/better interface for accurately determining which processes are using the webcam? Applications like [Oversight](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html) lead me to believe that there should be a better method of doing this.